# Making python library available to rqworker

Tags: python, ubuntu, redis

I have this module `foo` from which I want to import `foo.jobs`, the file structure is this.

```
foo
  | - __init__.py
  | - jobs.py
  | - ...
```

the problem is, I want to import it from outside of my program in a rqworker running on another folder.

I've tried adding this to my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/foo")
```

and I've tried adding this to ~/.profile

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/foo
```

Like I've seen here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath

but nothing works. Any idea on what could be happening? I'm using Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and playing with it, I discovered that you can put this in a config file so I created a file `rq_config.py` with the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/foo")

QUEUES = ['names','of','queues']
```

and it's working fine